# Scaling this Python code/making it more efficient

Tags: python, time-complexity

I wish to understand why this Python function does not scale well and how it can be improved hopefully by making it faster.

The aim of the code is to get the highest amount of stocks one can buy given an array A of stock prices and the amount of stocks of price A(i) is i+1. Explanation: Given list [2, 3, 4], one can only buy  one stock of price 2, two stocks of price 3 e.t.c.

```
def MaximumStockNumber (n, k, a):
    """a is a list of integers, k is the amount constraint and n is the number of integers"""
    numValuePairs = sorted([(index+1, value) for index, value in enumerate(a)], key = lambda x: x[1])
    stocks = 0
    for i in numValuePairs:
        a = i[0]
        if i[1]<=k:
            while a>0:
                if i[1]<=k:
                    stocks +=1
                    k = k-i[1]
                a -=1
        if k==0:
            return stocks
    return stocks
```

Comment: Why does it need to be faster? How will you determine whether it is fast enough?

Comment: It looks like homework! Can you explain your algorithm or put comments to help us understand how to improve it?

Comment: It looks like you've missed one more condition: the person has limited money, which is givven by k parameter. And what is n? It seems like you don't use it at all

Comment: Tbh, I do not understand the question? What are n, k and a? Why do you sort it? Because of your `A(i)` relation to `i+1`, I think you are at this the wrong way but you do not provide enough information.